# Запись данных в файл

Tags: c++

Обычно записи добавляются в конец файла. Как добавить в начало?

Comment: используйте флаги

Answer (score 2):

На каком языке пишете? Портить содержимое, на сколько я понимаю, нельзя? 
В таком случае, имхо, только считывать данные из файла в буфер, выполнять необходимые действия и перезаписывать файл.

Comment: С++? Извиняюсь. Не обратил внимание сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Читаете в конце файла размер Вашего буфера (читаем не по строкам, а допустим по 100KB). Т.е. первая позиция чтения 100K от конца файла.

Смещаетесь на размер вставки **от конца** и записываете буфер. Повторяете (двигаясь к началу файла), корректируя позиции чтения и записи.

Когда весь файл сдвинули, позиционируетесь в начало и записываете свои данные.

Answer (score 0):

При открытие файлового протока, можно задать параметр, чтобы файл не перезаписывался. Далее вам необходимо поставить курсор записи в нужное вам место (смотрите ф-ю `seekp`). Далее записывайте данные.

Comment: Только учтите, запись "поверх", хвост не сдвигается.

Comment: Поэтому я и спрашивал о том, можно ли портить содержимое. В предложенном Вами способе начало файла (та область, в которую будут записаны данные) будет испорчена. Открытие файла без перезаписи лишь оставит нетронутым содержимое на момент открытия. К тому же, если не указано иначе флагом ios::ate, курсор после открытия файла находится как раз в его начале.

Comment: avp - коротко и ясно. Именно "поверх".

Answer (score 0):

Если пишите в С-стиле, открываете файл с параметром "w" и далее с помощью fseek устанавливаете любое место, куда нужно писать, и пишите.

Comment: Опять же возвращаемся к тому, что запись будет "поверх".

Comment: Именно так. Но кажется, именно это и нужно.

Comment: Мне нужно не поверх

Comment: Тогда, либо новый файл на новом месте (в конце переименуете), либо сдвигать самому.

Comment: Самое оптимальное - как было уже сказано: считываете, в буфере делаете новый образ файла и записываете в файл из него с нуля. Можно и не в новый файл, но точно поверх старых данных.

Comment: Новый файл на новом месте - потом все равно придется добавлять содержимое старого в конец, удалять старый, переименовывать новый. Проще воспользоваться буфером.

Comment: Если файл без проблем помещается в память, то и говорить не о чем (по сути любой метод хорош). Видимо вопрос о том, что делать с **большим файлом**.

Comment: Не очень понял с "добавлять содержимое старого в конец" - это уж как получится. Есть смысл делать временный новый файл по меньшей мере в 2 случаях: 1) если файл имеет оооочень большие размеры и расположить его новый образ в памяти достаточно проблематично. Тогда считывается, переделывается и записывается по кусочкам. 2) есть риск в ходе создания нового диска получить ошибку в следствие обрыва потока данных для нового файла, аварийного завершения приложения и т.д. Тогда - делаем новый файл и когда все в порядке - переименовываем.

Comment: Все не то. Как проще тогда сделать, чтоб читало строки в файле с низу вверх?

Comment: Если Вам кажется, что Вас плохо понимают - сформулируйте вопрос по-новому, так, чтобы Вас поняли.

Comment: Вам чтоли файл вверх ногами перевернуть надо?